# Why can I replace both sides of the interval in the bisection method for optimization?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

In the bisection method for optimization, we look at the first derivative and then depending on whether it is positive or negative replace the boundary point a or b. I tried to implement it in python and it worked (at least for the simple examples I replicated). But it seems that I can arbitrarily change a=c and b=c positions and the code still works. Does anyone have an intuitive explanation for this or did I make an implementation mistake? In particular if you look at the picture, if I replace the wrong variable a,b with c I am left with the interval, where the optimum is not contained anymore, how can the code still be correct then?

[image]

Updated Code:

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def deriv(f, x, a=0.001):
   
   x1 = x
   x2 = x + a
   
   f_x1 = f(x1)
   f_x2 = f(x2)
   
   return (f_x2 - f_x1) / (x2 - x1)


def Bisection(f, R, tol=1e-9, nIter=100):
   
   a, b = R
   
   for it in range(nIter):
       
       c = (a+b) / 2
       
       df_c = deriv(f, c)
       
       if abs(df_c) < tol:
           break
       
       elif df_c > 0:
           a = c
           
       else:
           b = c
           
   c = (a + b) / 2
   
   return c


def alt_Bisection(f, R, tol=1e-9, nIter=100):
   
   a, b = R
   
   for it in range(nIter):
       
       c = (a+b) / 2
       
       df_c = deriv(f, c)
       
       if abs(df_c) < tol:
           break
       
       elif df_c > 0:
           b = c
           
       else:
           a = c
           
   c = (a + b) / 2
   
   return c


x = np.linspace(0,10, 101)
f = lambda x: -(x-5)**2
R = [2,8]

x_opt = Bisection(f, R)

plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.plot(x_opt, f(x_opt), "ro")

```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "I can arbitrarily change a=c and b=c positions and the code still works"? Can you write out exactly where you replace the code?

Better yet, write *both* functions, let's call them `Bisection_min_original` and `Bisectio_min_changed`, and then report what `Bisection_min_original(f, R)` and `Bisection_min_changed(f, R)` are equal to in your case.

Comment: Also, in your code, you call the function `Bisection_min`, yet you **define** the function `Bisection`. Are they the same function?

Comment: The [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) search the zero of a function. Applied to min/maximization, it amounts to searching the root of the first derivative.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I managed to change the code above. As 5xum pointed out, the initial problem was the interval I chose to test. Now it is still a bit unclear to me, whether the bisection and alt_bisection (where the positions b=c and a=c are switched)  are used for different purposes, i.e. bisection for maximization and alt_bisection for minimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is no longer correct if you make the changes in the appropriate lines. The code actually still works for `R=[2, 8]` because of the lucky coincidence that the function is completely symmetrical over the midpoint of that interval. Simply change `R` to something else, for example to `[0, 6]` or `[2, 10]` or something and you will see that the changes break the code behavior.

---

Example demonstrating how the changes in the code actually return incorrect results:

def Bi

```
section(f, df, R, nIter=100, tol=1e-7, original=False):
    a,b = R
    for it in range(nIter):
        c = (a+b) / 2      
        df_c = df(c) # f'(x_c)
        if abs(df_c) < tol:
            break
        elif df_c > 0:
            if original:
                a = c
            else:
                b = c
        else:
            if original:
                b = c
            else:
                a = c
            
    c = (a+b)/2
    return c

import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10, 101)
f = lambda x: -(x-5)**2
df = lambda x: -2*(x-5)
R = [2,10]

x_opt_original = Bisection(f, df, R, original=True)
x_opt_changed = Bisection(f, df, R, original=False)

print("Original method returns %f" % x_opt_original) # Prints 5.0, as expected
print("Changed method returns %f" % x_opt_changed) # Prints 10.0, which is incorrect!

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.plot(x_opt_original, f(x_opt_original), "ro")
plt.plot(x_opt_changed, f(x_opt_changed), "go")
plt.show()
```

the code also produces the following graph, where the red dot is found by the original method, while the green is found by the incorrectly modified method:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! So I chose a particular bad interval, got it. Am I right that one version of the code is for the maximization (here producing red dot) while the other version I would choose for minimization (here producing green dot)?

Comment: @MarlonBrando No, the other would be incorrect for minimization, as your original example shows.

Comment: Hi, I updated the code again (see above). It seems that now bisections works for maximization and alt_bisection for minimization. Just change f = lambda x: -(x-5)**2 to f = lambda x: (x-5)**2 and you will see. Would be glad, if you could quickly have a glance at it, whether now it is correctly implemented. The change in purpose for maximization/minimization would also make sense from intuition of the picture. If I want to go up the hill, I need to delete the left interval, whereas when I want to go down, I need to delete the other interval. Thanks!